# How to simplify the mode-line, and enter evil-insert-state depending on buffer name

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

[image]

Three questions actually, as stated in the title and shown in the figure.

Comment: Next time please post the text rather than embedding it in an image. It gains nothing and loses searchability. I'm sure you meant no harm by doing it though. :)

Comment: Also, I appreciate you trying to save posts, but these should be three separate questions, assuming you can't find the answers to any them elsewhere.